# How to find gradient of 3D plane defined by $3$ points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $3$ points in 3D space: $r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_3$.

What is the easiest way of finding the gradient of the plane that goes through these $3$ points? With gradient I mean the vector that shows the maximum slope direction and value.

Comment: If I well undertand your question, find the equation of the plane in the form $z=f(x,y)$, then $grad f(x,y)$ is the vector of maximum slope.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. How do I find the equation z = f(x,y) of the plante that goes through all three points?

Comment: look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_through_three_points